# Freeze During a Restart on ASPIRE 4751Z

Tags: dual-boot, freeze, windows-xp, reboot, aspire

I notice this happen every time with my ACER ASPIRE 4751Z.

Whenever I reboot from Ubuntu, the boot up freezes during "BIOS load". That means, the boot up menu isn't shown yet. I also have Windows XP installed and the same effect is rarely seen with Windows XP.

Well this post is more about an explanation rather than a solution. I want to know, what really happens during a reboot for this scenario to occur all the time. I was under the impression, during a reboot, the last instance of loaded OS has no presence, or does it occupy some resources that cause this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perhaps a hardware issue that exists in ACER ASPIRE 4751Z. This particular model is quite old now and the number of active users is decreasing. Therefore, this problem is too localized.